Can Sanctions Against Russia Be Modeled as a Dummy Variable in Econometric Analysis?
0
I am currently working on an econometric analysis where I aim to assess the impact of sanctions against Russia on the share of energy from renewable sources (% of total energy) in 28 EU countries.
I am considering modeling the sanctions as a dummy variable, where:
0 represents the periods when sanctions were not applied to Russia (before 2014). 1 represents the periods when sanctions were applied (2014 onwards). My dependent variable is the share of energy from renewable sources in each of these countries over a specified time period. I have a vector of control variables (GDP, energy prices, and policy incentives).
My questions are:
Is it appropriate to use a dummy variable to represent the imposition of sanctions in this context?
Are there any specific econometric models or techniques that would be recommended for analyzing the impact of such a binary treatment variable on a continuous outcome variable like the share of renewable energy?
I appreciate any insights or recommendations on best practices for this type of analysis!

Thank you for showcasing such a fascinating application of statistics and econometrics! Could you guide me on how I can explore similar projects in microeconomics? What types of topics would be ideal to delve into, and where did you find the dataset for your task?


Can Sanctions Against Russia Be Modeled as a Dummy Variable in Econometric Analysis?

You could model these sanctions as a dummy, but that would only tell you (assuming rest of the empirical strategy is sound) what is the total effect of the sanctioning period. Also, this approach would have problem capturing the increased number and severity of sanctions.
A simple alternative approach that would allow you to see the impact of severity would be to just include number of sanctions as another independent variable.
